# Make global npm scripts available to many subprojects

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, .npmrc

We have a monorepo with many subprojects.

```
root/
   complex/dir/layout/subproj1
   complex/dir/layout/subprojB 
   other/dir/subproj2
```

I'd like to have certain scripts available globally that were available to all the different subprojects.  An example is a script we've been using to deploy AWS lambdas, like

```
  "scripts": {
    "1up:slsdeploy": "npx serverless deploy --aws-profile prod --region 'us-west-2' --description $((git branch --show-current; git rev-parse --short HEAD; id -un) | tr '\\n' ' ')"
  },
```

Copying this and maintaining this in our 40 different lambdas isn't DRY.  An answer specifically about serverless is not the main goal, but that is the immediate issue.  But I would prefer more general techniques to make global scripts available to subprojects.

The most obvious answer -- just putting it in the root package.json does not appear to work (as dependencies do).

I also came across an interesting thing about the environment variables `npm` makes available (toward the end) at https://www.twilio.com/blog/npm-scripts that says you can reference settings in `.npmrc` like $npm_config_, so I though I might be able to put something in the top level `.npmrc`, like

```
MY_SPECIAL_CMD = "do something really special"
```

And then reference that in my individual package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "1up:slsdeploy": "$npm_config_MY_SPECIAL_CMD"
  },
```

which would be better, and maybe even MORE correct, since every predefined script may not be appropriate for every subproject.  But apparently this only applies to the DEFINED configuration settings for `.npmrc` (and npm silently ignores settings it doesn't recognize, which seems like a bug).  So this doesn't work.